# Can I redirect the page if condition is not true, without using an ActionResult return type?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I've seen a lot of similar posts, but nothing quite the same as what I'm trying to do. I'm pretty sure I'm doing this wrong, but can't find an answer that... well... redirects me in the right direction (no pun intended).

I've been amending some of the methods that Visual Studio created for me. What I want to do is refactor my code in order for a parent controller to define methods that would redirect users if a request was invalid for one reason or other. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
    protected Boolean CheckGoodRequest(Guid id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            RedirectToAction("BadRequestError");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
```

And in the parent class, I have the BadRequestError:

```
    protected ActionResult BadRequestError()
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "There was a bad request made, please try again");
    }
```

Now I've been reading that in order for ReturnToResult to work, it needs to be returned. The problem is, I can't use it in this kind of checking method as I'd need to return an ActionResult.

In addition, when I start trying to test these invalid scenarios, (such as when a user is trying to view another's parameter), it passes these redirects, and allows access.

Is there no way for me to check these independently in their own boolean return value methods without needing to return an ActionResult? Or is there a different process I can do to redirect a user to an error page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't find anything to suggest that it is possible to redirect without returning it, but I figured out a solution by changing my boolean method to a void that could throw an exception as follows:

```
    protected void CheckGoodRequest(Guid id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(400, "There was something wrong with your request. Please try again.");
        }
    }
```

This allows me to have this check not return an ActionResult, and still give me the ability to check records that can be inherited by child classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a wrong way to use RedirectToAction. Hope the code below can help in some way.

```
public ActionResult MyMethod()
{
    .....
    //Check the GUID ??
    if (id == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("BadRequestError");
    }

    .....
}
```

Sorry if I understand wrongly.

Comment: Thanks, yes. I think I'm trying to be too efficient in refactoring my code, as it's causing these kinds of problems. As my question states,  I'm wondering if I can get some form of redirect without needing to return it. I'm guessing not by the looks of things!

Comment: Actually, as my default route is controller/action/id, and the Guid is not "Guid?", if there's is a null, I get an ArgumentException. Therefore, (as it's an invalid scenario) I'm guessing this check is somewhat redundant. Would you agree?